# JTable : No selected row

Tags: java, swing

I want to disable a button whenever there aren't any rows selected in a jTable. Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [SelectionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) on your JTable.

```
JTable table = new JTable();
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setEnabled(false);

ListSelectionModel listSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
listSelectionModel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) { 
            ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
            button.setEnabled(!lsm.isSelectionEmpty());
});
```

Comment: better yet, remove the if/else and just button.setEnabled(!lsm.isSelectionEmpty());

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting())
        {
            boolean rowsAreSelected = table.getSelectedRowCount() > 0;
            button.setEnabled(rowsAreSelected);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no ListSelectionEvent fired then? I would be very surprised if that's the case...

Answer (score 0):

Add an selection Listener to your table. If an selection occurs, enable the button. Let the Button be disabled by default.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Comment: That link is to a old version of the API